# yii2 active record query

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I need to make query (in search model) where:

1. Get current row index (not id)
2. Do a manipulation with that count (multiply this on constant number) and add if condition (if 'row index' > 10)
3. See this count in the model

Some steps I resolve:

1. I know how to create 'new column' and see it in the gridview:

   ```
   $query->select([
       '{{tour}}.*',
       '(1000 / 'need to add row index' ) as points' //$points
   ]);
   ```
2. I know how to get a current index, but with active record:

```
MyModel::find()->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'cumulative_points', $playerPoints])->count();
```

But I need to combine this query. Anybody can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you need you can express the content of SQL part like literal and then assign the select content you prefer (not using array / hash assignment)  this way

```
 $query->select(' tour.*, 1000 / id ) as points' )
```

Sostantially you can assign to activeQuery select() method exactly the select part of you query ..

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html